# Using php, how to save a smaller than 16mb images in mongoDB using BSON

Tags: php, image, mongodb, bson

I need some help:

I am creating a web application in php and uses the database mongodb.

Because it is a bank nosql got the idea that I need to save the images in the proper database.

Research in mongoDB documentation, I found that I need to use the BSON type to save in the bank because it is less than 16mb images.

The problem is that I do not know how.

I need to transform the image. Jpg in a string?
  and then use the bson_encode?

I'm trying this way:

```
$data = file_get_contents('../images/1.png');

$connection = new Mongo();

$db = $connection->aaaa;

$suspeitos = $db->imagens;

$susp = array(     
'imagem'  => $data,
); 

$suspeitos->insert($susp);
```

But this is not working.

Someone has already done something similar, and could help me save an image in mongoDB with BSON?

thanks

Comment: Saving images directly in a database, regaurdless of the type of database is generally a bad idea. If you do want to store files in mongo, use Mongo GridFS.

Answer (score 0):

MongoDB has a build in File System called GridFS for storing files within MongoDB itself. You get all of the advantages of Shards and Replication and query of MongoDB. The files are broken up into chunks so you don't run into the 16MB document size limit.

http://php.net/manual/en/class.mongogridfs.php

Comment: then even for files less than 16mb the best way is still using GridFS?

Comment: "best" is a relative term, but yes you could use GridFS to store profile images for users even if they are really small.